# OAuth2.0 - maximum requests for refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Is there any maximum number of requests to get a brand new access token using a refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 25 according to [Google's developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration)

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I have a refresh token to make requests to an endpoint and then return me an access token. My question was how many requests to that endpoint can I make using the same refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens have a lifetime of 3600 seconds. Requesting a new access token before that time is up works fine but it's inefficient for your app to do so often. I don't think Google publishes a limit on how many non-expired access tokens a refresh token can have but you may get errors and it's non-optimal.

For most apps, refreshing an access token 10 minutes before the current access token expires (later if your not to worried about clock drift) works well.

Answer (score 0):

The number of requests depend on the authorization server security policy. 
Some servers allow only one request (the refresh token is invalidate after the request), other servers may allow 10, 100 or even unlimited requests.